# Rewrite Lambda expression with System.Linq.Expressions APIs

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am stuck on this for hours. All I want to do is build an Expression tree by rewriting this following expression using [Expression class APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx#inheritanceContinued):

```
var Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => x.SomeProperty == value;
```

What I got so far are:

```
{
     var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
     var lhs = Expression.Property(param, "SomeProperty");
     var rhs = Expression.Constant(value, value.GetType());
     return Expression.Call(typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public), lhs, rhs);
}
```

This works fine if `T` is a primitive type or enumeration. But I got an exception if T is a reference type, a `class` etc.

Exception Message:

> Unable to create a constant value of type '`TypeName`'. Only primitive
>   types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.constantexpression(v=vs.110).aspx) I would assume that you can't create a `ConstantExpression` from anything but a *compile time* constant. Which is consistent with the error message you're getting since *primitive types and enumeration types* are the only ones that support *compile time* constants. Where is the value of `value` coming from?

Comment: Have you tried using Reflector's expression tree lookup? http://blogs.msmvps.com/paulomorgado/2010/08/05/mastering-expression-trees-with-net-reflector/

Comment: The value is a property of a DataContract. It is deserialized by the WCF. I then use the deserialized object to build an expression.

Comment: @FrankLiu I think you might be using the wrong kind of Expression. I can't fully confirm though, but I strongly suspect that `ConstantExpression` is for *compile time* constants such as `var a = 5;` or `var b = "Hello!";` and the like.

Comment: @HighCore, I agree that I am using the wrong expression. Which one should I use? But if I create an value object and use it in the solution given from Christophano, it works. What is the difference here?

Comment: @HighCore A `ConstantExpression` does not have to be a compile-time constant, it's merely a fixed value. Think of it like a `readonly` field.

Comment: @FrankLiu What can you tell us about the type `TypeName`?

Comment: @Christophano, it is nothing fancy just a POCO class with a couple of public properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression generated was passed to a Linq `Where` call. Like this.

```
 Context.Sources.Where(criteria.BuildQuery());
```

The exception was thrown when the expression is being evaluated/translated.

If I compile the expression and then pass a delegate to the `Where` call, everything works as expected.

```
 Context.Sources.Where(criteria.BuildQuery().Compile());
```

I am not sure what difference it makes, if someone knows why please enlighten us.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the type explicitly, in this case, as long as the value is not null (which I'm assuming it isn't, as you're calling `GetType()` on it).

This should do it.

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
var property = Expression.Property(param, "SomeProperty");
var compareValue = Expression.Constant(value);
var equals = Expression.Equal(property, compareValue);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equals, param);
```

Comment: I started without the explicit type. But it didnot work.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more information about the domain then. I've just tried this in a quick console app and it works fine to create a simple equality expression. What type is T when it's throws the exception?

Comment: your solution is good. I tested in a quick console application and it works as expected. My real code is bit more complicated. Let me edit my question a bit and see where does the gap fall. Thank you.